# Get distinct count in a group to take account of only most recent record

Tags: mysql, group-by, crystal-reports, max, distinct-values

I am looking at summarising the number of drugs prescribed, per patient for a patient's *most recent stay* in hospital. In my group output I currently have:

```
Patient ref 1234,Total Drugs 9
Patient ref 3456, Total Drugs 12
```

However in this example lets say the total number of drugs in the most recent stay in hospital (as opposed to all stays) should actually be:

```
Patient ref 1234,Total Drugs 6
Patient ref 3456, Total Drugs 10
```

When I put all the drugs and other information in "Details" I have been able to restrict successfully to display only drugs in most recent stay in hospital by 
using Selection Formulas, Group Selection:

```
({patient_stay.lnkstay} = Maximum({patient_stay.lnkstay},{patient_number}))
```

NB If a patient has had three stays in hospital, the field patient_stay.lnkstay would display 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 with 3.00 being the most recent. However in my group results:

```
Patient ref 1234,Total Drugs 9
Patient ref 3456, Total Drugs 12
```

I cannot seem to get the DistinctCount (currently used to produce Total drugs 9 and 12) to only count for the most recent stay for each patient. So I need a way to DistinctCount only on those drugs associated with the most recent stay for each patient (using maximum on field patient_stay.lnkstay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a bit on your logic. Try this:

create second group with `{patient_stay.lnkstay}` and take summaries in group footer 2.

Now use below logic in supress of group header 2 and group footer 2

```
({patient_stay.lnkstay} = Maximum({patient_stay.lnkstay},{patient_number}))
```

Totally supress Details, Group Header1 and Group footer1

Comment: Hi Siva. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am getting blank results so must be doing something wrong. I created a group {patient_stay.lnkstay} and placed it in Group header 2 and also in Group footer 2. I then moved my Patient Ref number and Distinctcount of Drugs from Group Footer 1 to group footer 2. I then right clicked on Group header 2, Section Expert and alongside Suppress clicked on x-2 and put in formula ({x_patient_spell.lnkspell} = Maximum({x_patient_spell.lnkspell},{patient_basic.hospital_no})). Did the same for Group Footer 2. I get no results.  Not sure what I am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: oh and I did suppress everything else, other than page header

Comment: have you took the summaries in group footer 2 when fields are placed in details?

Comment: By summaries do you mean my "Distinctcount of patients" that were originally displayed in group footer 1?

Comment: I meant "Distinctcount of drugs"

Comment: yes which ever either distinct count or sum which ever suits you in group footer 2 along with group footer 1

Comment: I have got results to appear but the numbers are the same so I am still not getting numbers just for the maximum (ie most recent) patient_stay.lnkstay.  Thanks for your help anyway. I appreciate its difficult when you cant see exactly what I have done. Regards

Comment: NP tell me which group you have supressed and which one is visible depending on that you will be able to see the result also if it is possible show the rough representation of the report

Comment: sorry didn't mean to send that. stand by

Comment: PART 1Group Header 1   Not Suppressed.   GROUP #1: Ward (also I also need to show the patients grouped into wards. 
Group Header 2. Suppressed. Nothing in the field
Group Header 3. Suppressed. Hospital Number (ie patient ref)
Group Header 4. Not Suppressed. GROUP #4 InkSpell (the one you suggested I set up, this is the one I need to restrict using MAXIMUM)
Details. Suppressed. Various fields
Group Footer 4. Not suppressed. GROUP #4 InkSpell,   PatientName, Distinctcount of Drugs
Group Footer 3. Suppressed. Nothing in the field

Comment: PART 2 Group Footer #2b. Not Suppressed. GROUP #2: Hospital Number,   PatientName, Distinctcount of Drugs
Group Footer #1. Suppressed. Group #1 Ward

Comment: PART 3 NB Group Selection Formula as follows
DistinctCount ({x_med_orders.drug_description}, {patient_basic.hospital_no}) >= 5 and
({x_patient_spell.lnkspell} = Maximum({x_patient_spell.lnkspell},{patient_basic.hospital_no}))

I get output like this 
Hospital Number  Patient Name   Number of Drugs
WARD A 
11111    wwwwww   18
WARD B
22222    xxxxxxxxx   12
33333                 yyyyyyyyy   20

WARD C
44444    zzzzzzzzzz   29

Comment: PART 4    Showing patients by ward and their number of drugs (if they have over 5)

To clarify, this is coming out as expected, except that I know the number of drugs is too high as it should show the number of drugs for the patient’s most recent stay(spell) not all their stays in hospital. 
This most recent stay(spell) can be identified by taking the MAXIMUM number in field lnkspell and its this that I cannot get to work in conjunction with the grouping.

Comment: ok in that case summary of group footer 4 and supress remaining 3 using the logic

Comment: Ok thanks. That seems to have worked. Many many thanks for your help and patience

Comment: No Problem..Accept it as answered so that others can use